# Apache beam CombinePerKey(sum) is not summing correctly

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to count the occurrence of every field 'size' I have in my data:

```
counts = (
    lines
    | 'convert_to_dict' >> beam.Map(process_data)
    | 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(1*1),accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
    | 'GettinyCounty' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x['size'])
    | 'PairWithOne' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1))
    | 'Sum' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum))
```

Printing the results on the console

```
def format_result(size_count):
  (size, count) = size_count
  out = {}
  out["size"] = size
  out["count"] = count
  print("{}".format(out))
  return  str(out)

output = counts | 'format_result' >> beam.Map(format_result)
            | 'encode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8')).with_output_types(bytes)))

output | beam.io.WriteToPubSub(known_args.output_topic)
```

Here's what I get. I expected something like:

{'medium' : 155} , {'small' : 75},...}

[image]

Comment: What is the input data source ?

Comment: You are windowing into rather small window intervals. When you apply windowing, your aggregations happen and produce output 'per window', meaning you can have multiple results per 'size'. This might depend on the input data you send to the pipeline. If your data is spread in time, this can be an expected result. Please, provide more information on data you feed to pipeline.

Comment: By the way, I think it's better to use `beam.combiners.Count.PerElement()` if you want just calculate the count of something.

Comment: It works. How can I get it grouped by timestamp?
example : 2017-04-05 12:00:00 medium : 12, small:1

Comment: Can you supply the question with the input data and the expected result based on the comments suggests?